# Using register/login actions in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a problem starting a new asp.net application. I choose asp.net mvc template with Individual User Accounts authentication and project generates and starts normally. My question is: what do i have to do to use register/login options? From what I understood methods responsible for these actions are generated automatically, but should I do something about database schema for information about users (shoudn't it be created also automatically?).

Anyway, after filling fields in register form i get error that a file couldn't be found and the error is found on line 155: *var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);*

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015 on windows 8. Thank you in advance

Comment: Check one of the many tutorials on MVC. This *is* covered in all of them. Try http://asp.net/mvc or Microsoft's Virtual Academy

Comment: for your first question - ya everything is automatic. for the 2nd - did you change anything in the project?

Comment: I didn't change anything.

Comment: "after filling fields in register form i get error that a file couldn't be found and the error is found "- What is the name of the that not found?!

Comment: It just says server error in application in main catalog " '/' ".

Answer (score 0):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterVM registerVM)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View();
        }

        AppUser appUser = new AppUser()
        {
            Fullname = registerVM.Fullname,
            UserName = registerVM.Username,
            Email = registerVM.Email
        };
        IdentityResult result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(appUser, registerVM.Password);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
            }
            return View(registerVM);
        }

        await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(appUser, Roless.Admin.ToString());
        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(appUser, true);
        return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
    }
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginVM loginVM, string returnurl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View();
        }

        AppUser dbUser = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(loginVM.Email);
        if (dbUser == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Ya email ya da Password sehvdir");
            return View(loginVM);
        }
        SignInResult result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(dbUser, loginVM.Password, loginVM.RememerMe, true);


        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Your Account Is Lock Out");
            return View(loginVM);
        }

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Ya Email ya da Password sehvdir");
            return View(loginVM);
        }
        if (returnurl == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
        }
        foreach (var item in await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(dbUser))
        {
            if (item.Contains(Roless.Admin.ToString()))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("index", "Dashboard", new { area = "AdminF" });
            }
        }
        return Redirect(returnurl);

    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).